# questions about parent and child forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have encountered a issue. here is my question:

1). In form1 there is a timer, and in this timer I will new form2 every 1 minutes. (I am using form2.Show())

2). when form1 at the head of my desktop,the form2 could be shown without any problems. And there are multiple form2 have been shown, this is my excepted.
But, when the form1 has been minimized in the status bar, then form2 will be not been shown on desktop and it will be shown as minimized in status bar.

so whether I could show form2 at the head of my desktop and even there are many other windows displayed in desktop, I want that the newest form2 will be shown at the head of desktop even form1 has been minimized.
Thank you anybody. :)

Comment: Can't do it. If your application's process has been taken out of the foreground by the user, then it cannot regain the foreground without user intervention.

Comment: so when the form1 has not been shown minimized in status bar, whether form2 could be shown at the head of my desktop? in my side this situation could not also been implemented, even though I used form2.top

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. If Form1 has been minimized, and another application is in the foreground, then your application no longer has foreground privileges. That means any other windows it tries to display (like Form2) won't be in the foreground, either. There is no way to force your windows into the foreground unless the *user* brings your application to the foreground. Now, you can certainly display a non-minimized window, and that should be the default. But it won't be focused unless the user wants it to be focused. You cannot steal the focus from another app.